# Using enclosing WordPress shortcodes to pass $content

Tags: wordpress, shortcode

I'm trying to use shortcodes for a glossary function. The function connects to a database, queries the word and returns the definition.

Currently, it works if I use self-closing shortcodes.

For example:

```
    function defineGlossary($atts) {
    extract(shortcode_atts(array(
    'term' => '0'
    ), $atts));

    // connect to database and grab definition

    $glossary_output .= "<span title='";
    $glossary_output .= $result_definition;
    $glossary_output .= "'>";
    $glossary_output .= $term;
    $glossary_output .= "</span>";
    return $glossary_output;
    }
    add_shortcode("glossary", "defineGlossary");
```

[glossary="administrator"] as a shortcode works great with this code. It returns

```
    <span title="definition pulled from the database">administrator</span>.
```

I'd prefer to use an enclosing shortcose such as [glossary]administrator[/glossary] Unfortunately, I cannot get this to work since I don't know how (or if it's possible) to pass the $content as a variable (to send to the database and find the definition).

**Update from below. If I simplify it to:**

```
    <?php
    function defineGlossary($atts, $shortcodeContent = null) {
    $glossary_output .= "<span title='";
    $glossary_output .= "Sample Definition";
    $glossary_output .= "'>";
    $glossary_output .= $shortcodeContent;
    $glossary_output .= "</span>";
    return $glossary_output;
    }
    add_shortcode("glossary", "defineGlossary");
    ?>
```

And use [glossary]administrator[/glossary] it just returns [glossary]administrator in the content.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add a second variable to your function to handle the shortcode content. This will be passed along if it exists.

```
 function defineGlossary($atts, $shortcodeContent = null) {
     if (is_null( $content )) {
         //handle if shortcode isn't defined 
     }

     // connect to database and grab definition
     $glossary_output .= "<span title='";
     $glossary_output .= $result_definition;
     $glossary_output .= "'>";
     $glossary_output .= $shortcodeContent;
     $glossary_output .= "</span>";
     return $glossary_output;
 }
 add_shortcode("glossary", "defineGlossary");
```

I didn't test this, but I think it does what you want.

Comment: I thought that would work as well, but it doesn't. If I try to pass the $content though, I just end up with: [glossary]administrator showing up.

Comment: There must be something amiss in your code then. If you just echo `$content` what do you get?

Comment: I updated the example above to show you what I'm trying now. I still get the same result.

Comment: Disable all your plugins then and switch to the twenty ten theme. Something is messing stuff up. If you have caching enabled then flush the cache before running your next test. Something is breaking somewhere. Hard to tell what without a bunch of troubleshoting =(

Comment: I'll dig into it more - thanks. It's strange that I can get it to work fine if I use a self-closing shortcode.

Comment: I think shortcode functions need to be lowercase. the shortcode api says do not use CamelCase etc.